# ECDiffieHellmanCng Get ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey from Byte[]

Tags: c#, cryptography

I am implementing DiffieHellman key exchange for my server but after i receive the other party public key which is converted to `Byte[]` i can't convert it back to `ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey` to use it in the `DeriveKeyMaterial`

Here is my code:

```
var socket = state.Socket;
var buffer = state.Buffer;
var alice = new ECDiffieHellmanCng
{
    KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash,
    HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256
};
var exchangePacket = new ExchangeMessage(144, (int)PacketType.Exchange)
{
    PublicKey = alice.PublicKey.ToByteArray()
};
var len1 = socket.Send(exchangePacket, 0, exchangePacket.Length, SocketFlags.None);
if (0 >= len1) {
    return false;
}
var len2 = socket.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
if (len2 <= 0)
    return false;
Array.Resize(ref buffer, len2);
var bob = new ExchangeMessage(buffer); //HOW TO GET ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey FROM MY BYTE[]
byte[] aliceKey = alice.DeriveKeyMaterial(/*Can't get ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey from byte[]*/);
```

Comment: Is `len2 == len1`? TCP can split up one `Send` call into multiple `Receive` calls, or unify multiple `Send` calls into a single `Receive` call. So you must send the length, and then read in a loop until you got enough data.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancngpublickey.frombytearray(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Loki, even if i had a buffer with 65535 length ?

Comment: @SLaks what is the blob format ?

Comment: @RuneS: Probably the same as from `ToByteArray()`

Comment: @RuneS Buffer size is irrelevant. That's how TCP works, its a stream, not a sequence of messages.

Comment: @Loki so that generates another knowledge hole... this needs some research. as i create my main server without that into account.

Comment: @SLaks idk where i can get that BlobFormat

Comment: @Loki any useful links ?

Comment: @SLaks, can't you tell me what is the BlobFormat and how to determine ?

Answer (score 0):

Will this is how i got it to work

```
DeriveKeyMaterial(ECDiffieHellmanCngPublicKey.FromByteArray(bob.PublicKey, new CngKeyBlobFormat("ECCPUBLICBLOB")));
```