# Handling TCP Packet Fragmentation

Tags: c#, sockets

Well it seems very ambiguous to me how Packet Fragmentation occurs as it never happens with my Local tests and i don't know what to do in order to handle a fragmented packet before notifying my application that i actually received some info.

Here is the way i receive from a connected Client Socket

```
var asynchronousState = (AsynchronousState) ar.AsyncState; // AsynchronousState is an entity that Holds each connected socket's Buffer, IPEndPoint and so on...
try {
    Socket socket = asynchronousState.Socket;
    int length = socket.EndReceive(ar);
    if (0 != length) {
        if (null != ClientReceive) {
            var bytes = new byte[length];
            Array.Copy(asynchronousState.Buffer, bytes, length);
            ClientReceive(asynchronousState, bytes);
            Array.Clear(asynchronousState.Buffer, 0, asynchronousState.Buffer.Length);
        }
        if (socket.Connected) {
            socket.BeginReceive(asynchronousState.Buffer, 0, asynchronousState.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, HandleAsyncReceive, asynchronousState);
            return;
        }
    }
    DisposeSocket(asynchronousState);
}
catch (SocketException exception) {
    if (exception.SocketErrorCode != SocketError.Disconnecting &&
        exception.SocketErrorCode != SocketError.NotConnected &&
        exception.SocketErrorCode != SocketError.ConnectionReset &&
        exception.SocketErrorCode != SocketError.ConnectionAborted &&
        exception.SocketErrorCode != SocketError.Shutdown) {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
        Core.Logger.Log(exception);
    }

    DisposeSocket(asynchronousState);
}
```

How i construct my Packets

```
public class ExchangeMessage : PacketStructure //Packet Structure is a custom builder similar to `BinaryWrite/Reader` : This returns a byte[] or builds from a byte[]
{
    public int Length;
    public int Type;

    public byte[] PublicKey
    {
        get { return ReadArray(140, 4); }
        set { WriteArray(value, 4); }
    }

    public ExchangeMessage(byte[] receivedPacket) : base(receivedPacket) {}

    public ExchangeMessage(int length, int type) : base(length, type)
    {
        Length = length;
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

**Now that i invoke the `ClientReceive` event handler whenever i receive something expecting  that the application will be able to deserialize or rebuild my Packet back. `What if the packet was fragmented ?`**

I am very confused as by researching the topic i find a lot of different opinions among them was something i am skeptical about that says *`If you are building your Packet by yourself, it will not be fragmented!`*

Comment: 1) TCP doesn't use packets. You may be confused with UDP. 2) If you are constructing packets on top of TCP, you will have to be aware that you won't get the entirety of a packet at one time. You will need to have length fields, etc., to reconstruct the packet.

Comment: @BobDalgleish: So i should change the socket type to UDP and i am good to go ?, and i used TCP should i call EndReceive again in order to get the more of a data sent ? or how to handle such behave ? Sorry i am totally clueless.

Comment: @Bob: Of course TCP uses packets.  I think you mean that boundaries aren't preserved to the user.

Comment: Read this related question [clientStream.Read returns wrong number of bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575659/clientstream-read-returns-wrong-number-of-bytes). For binary data I recommend writing out the length of each message and then reading in a loop until you received the complete message.

Comment: @Loki: That's got nothing to do with packet fragmentation, which occurs in the IP layer.

Comment: For context: This is a follow up to an [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237959/ecdiffiehellmancng-get-ecdiffiehellmanpublickey-from-byte) where I wrote: "TCP can split up one Send call into multiple Receive calls, or unify multiple Send calls into a single Receive call. So you must send the length, and then read in a loop until you got enough data."

Comment: @BenVoigt I think the OP is a bit confused about their higher level messages which they call packets and the unrelated IP packets. My original comment (which probably triggered this question) was about these higher level messages (Send/Receive calls) not about low level IP details.

Comment: @Loki: Perhaps... but I think we can explain what's going on without becoming complicit in redefinition of "TCP Packet Fragmentation" to mean something other than "TCP packets fragmented by the IP layer"

Comment: @BenVoigt Is there a chance that my Message will not arrive as whole ?  the answer seems to be `yes`. However i because more confused after i saw your discussion :D, so please be patient because we are going to a long one :).

Comment: @Rune: Read the italicized part of my answer.  You are not in control of TCP packets.  The Sockets API will turn your application messages into however many TCP packets it thinks is best.

Comment: @BenVoigt see my comment on the your answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt Of course, I mean that TCP does not use packets. It is a continuous stream of data. Any packets that you want to transport must be maintained by your application. TCP uses IP packets at a lower level, but it is not, by definition, a packet protocol.

Comment: @Bob: An "IP packet with a TCP header" is a "TCP packet".  This is the terminology used by *every expert* and even codified in the Internet standards themselves.  I suggest you adopt it as well.

Answer (score 6):

The Sockets API won't deliver you packet fragments, only complete packets.  The TCP/IP stack will buffer received fragments until it has a complete packet, and if some fragments are lost the whole packet will be discarded and have to be retransmitted in its entirety.

This is one reason that Path MTU detection improves performance -- it prevents mid-channel fragmentation and the corresponding increase in packet error rates.  Sending smaller packets will result in just as many errors, but entire lost packets can be dealt with via selective-ACK which is much more efficient than discarding received fragments of a partial packet.

If you used a lower-level networking API you might be able to see packet fragments.

---

*Note that TCP packets do not correspond 1:1 to `send()` calls.  The Nagle algorithm can combine multiple writes into a single packet, and a single write which is larger than the path MTU will generate multiple packets.  I think this is what Bob was alluding to in his comment.*

---

Fragmentation, packet loss, and retransmission is all handled inside TCP/IP. Your application doesn't need to worry about it. Your application should treat a TCP socket as a stream of bytes.

The bytes you put in come out in the same order. How long it takes and how many come out at once is not guaranteed and is beyond your control.

Since you want to treat your data as having structure, not mere bytes, you will have to add that structure yourself.  Length prefixes and record separators are both popular ways of doing this.

For example, HTTP uses record separators for the command/response and metadata.  The HTTP command and all headers are separated by `\r\n`.  The disadvantage is that if separators appear in the data they need to be escaped.  [This example is borrowed from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Example_session).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 131
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close

<html>
<head>
  <title>An Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello World, this is a very simple HTML document.
</body>
</html>
```

Length-prefixing is also used.  The `Content-Length` header gives the length of the payload.  This allows any byte to appear in the payload.

Comment: So you mean that i don't need to worry about the `Fragmentation` ? and just if i encountered some error rebuilding my Message (or Packet) i simply re-request it ?.

Comment: If you see in my receive function i EndReceive, then check if Length is more than 0 i just notify my Handler that i received a message which the Handler switch through it's `Type` which i wrote into it.

Comment: @Rune: Fragmentation, packet loss, and retransmission is all handled inside TCP/IP.  Your application doesn't need to worry about it.  Your application should treat a TCP socket as a stream of bytes.  The bytes you put in come out in the same order.  How long it takes and how many come out at once is not guaranteed.

Comment: so to come to conclusion what is the best situation that any big programs that relay on TCP use in order to some how guarantee that they Handle (whole messages), as if i passed incomplete message to my Message Handler it may result in an exception.

Comment: Examples would be very appreciated.

Comment: @RuneS: Someone needs to put a message back together before handling it.  Somewhere between "I got some bytes" and "Here is a message", you have to find the message boundaries.

Comment: Before i send my `ExchangeMessage` as seen in my topic, the Length is already a part of it. i may read the length and see how much i expect to read but then what ?, can i keep calling EndReceive inside a while or something... i don't know how would that be achieved regarding the way i created my SocketServer

Comment: @RuneS: Append the bytes onto a `List<byte>` until you have as many as the Length told you to expect, then pull them out and send them to message handler.  You will probably have some bytes left over in the List.  Keep them around until the next receive completes.

Comment: you seem to know a lot, and the more you speak them more questions i will have :D. what is the `payload` and from your point of view (to prevent having you annoyed from my questions) and given the code i provided what would you do to Handle such situation.

Comment: Can you psuedo edit my code to achieve that behave as i am more of a practical learner ? i will understand better if you show me, and i am soooo sorry for taking a lot of your time.